# Python creating nested dictionary from a List with repeating keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, dictionary

I am trying to convert the list to a dictionary. 
I have a list of list like this and some of the first values of mini lists are repeating:

```
list = [["DDS 500","A",300], ["DDS 500","B",100], ["AGB 850","C",250], ["AGB 850","B",350], ["UNI 100","D",900]]
```

The first value of mini lists will be key . Then, for each mini list second and third value  will be the "value" for that key and the values also should be a dictionary. As a result, Final dictionary should be like this:

```
dict = { "DDS 500":{"A":300,"B":100}, "AGB 850":{"C":250,"B":350}, "UNI 100":{"D":900} }
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this issue? What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: I tried to create the dictionary, but since some of the values ​​in the list are repeated, it only gave the dictionary the value saw first. For example, ` dict = {"DDS 500: {" A ": 300}, .. ` @jordanm

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst= [["DDS 500","A",300], ["DDS 500","B",100], ["AGB 850","C",250], ["AGB 850","B",350], ["UNI 100","D",900]]

out=defaultdict(dict)

for k,ik,iv in lst:
    out[k].update({ik:iv})
```

---

Output:

```
defaultdict(dict,
            {'DDS 500': {'A': 300, 'B': 100},
             'AGB 850': {'C': 250, 'B': 350},
             'UNI 100': {'D': 900}})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dict.setdefault` if you do not want to import any module:

```
result = {}

for k1, k2, v in my_list:
    result.setdefault(k1, {})[k2] = v
result
```

output:

```
{'DDS 500': {'A': 300, 'B': 100},
 'AGB 850': {'C': 250, 'B': 350},
 'UNI 100': {'D': 900}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in two steps:  1) create the dictionary with all keys and and empty dictionary as value, 2) merge the values as dictionaries into each key:

```
lst = [["DDS 500","A",300], ["DDS 500","B",100], ["AGB 850","C",250], ["AGB 850","B",350], ["UNI 100","D",900]]

d = { k:dict() for k,*_ in lst }
for k,*v in lst: d[k].update(dict([v]))
```

output:

```
print(d)

# {'DDS 500': {'A': 300, 'B': 100}, 'AGB 850': {'C': 250, 'B': 350}, 'UNI 100': {'D': 900}}
```